# set Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG in textView

Tags: android, listview

i have the problem about when user click the `checkbox` inside the `listView` , the `textView` will no charge it to `Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)` . When the user click the `checkbox` ,the strike line will display in the `textView` .

```
           public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor c) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            listName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.produtName);
            listCheck = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.check);
                            Item tag = (Item) listCheck.getTag();
            String pos = helper.getProductId(c);
            Log.i(CN, "getView: no tag on " + pos);
            tag = new Item();
            tag.id = Integer.parseInt(pos);
            listCheck.setTag(tag);
            listCheck.setChecked(false);
                        String status = helper.getProductStatusT(c);
            if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 0) {
                listCheck.setChecked(true);
                listName.setPaintFlags(listName.getPaintFlags()
                        | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            } else {
                listCheck.setChecked(false);
                listName.setPaintFlags(listName.getPaintFlags()
                        & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            }


           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View tmpView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            Log.i(CN, "getView:" + position);
            final CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            Item tag = (Item) cBox.getTag();

            cBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Item tag = (Item) v.getTag();
                    if (tag == null)
                        Log.i(CN, "checkbox clicked no tag");

                    else

                        helper.updateStatus(tag.id);

                    Log.i(CN, "checkbox clicked tag=" + tag.id);

                 }
                    if (cBox.isChecked()) {
                        Log.i(CN, " Checked!");
                        // do some operations here
                    } else {
                        Log.i(CN, "NOT Checked!");
                        // do some operations here
                        helper.updateStatus2(tag.id);
                    }
                }
            });
            return tmpView;
        }
```

the checkBox work fine . But the problem is when user click the checkbox , the strike line will  not display out . Anyone know where should i put the

```
listName.setPaintFlags(listName.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: firstly you use `bindView` in conjunction with `newView`, then there's no need for getView. use `newView` to inflate your viewgroup xml, then do all your code in `bindView`. But why are you setting and getting tags here?

Comment: i try it before , but recycling mechanism of listview....i want to get the productID ,when user click the checkbox , then update to database according productID

Comment: the productStatus is updated to database when user click the checkbox ...but didnt display the strike line ...is it listName.setPaintFlags(listName.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG); need to put inside   public View getView  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i might have an idea what you might be trying now, see if the following is working for you:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    private boolean[] arrCb;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        arrCb = new boolean[c.getCount()];
        // ^ this will hold the checkbox states
        resetArrcb();
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.lv_row, parent, false);
        // inflate the xml that the textView and checkbox is in
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        // you do everything else here. there's no need for getView when you use newView and bindView
        final TextView listName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.produtName);
        final CheckBox listCheck = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.check);

        if (arrCb[cursor.getPosition()]) {
            listCheck.setChecked(true);
            listName.setPaintFlags(listName.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        } else {
            listCheck.setChecked(false);
            listName.setPaintFlags(listName.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
        }

        listCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listCheck.isChecked()) {
                    arrCb[cursor.getPosition()] = true;
                } else {
                    arrCb[cursor.getPosition()] = false;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    private void resetArrcb() {
        // i'm using this to fill the collection but you could easily loop through your 
        // database to fill it with the correct values.
        for (int i = 0; i < arrCb.length; i++) {
            arrCb[i] = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Then i'm not sure, but it seems like you'd want to adjust your database depending on what is selected. I'd suggest doing it when everything is all over, when your activity is being exited. perhaps set a new method that will just loop through the checkbox collection then do what you intended in the database. it should match 1 to 1 with with table rows.

**EDIT**

Even even better, make a getter method to return your array instead so you can do your database operations right in your activity.

Comment: i just edited my post. maybe perhaps it is more comprehensive now.

Comment: arrCb[cursor.getPosition() , this is get position from database? i not understand this part

Comment: yes it is. `cursor.getPosition()` returns what position of your query that your cursor is currently on. you use that number to correspond with what position of your array that you want to effect.

Comment: int flags ...what value i need to pass?model = helper.getAllProduct(list);
   startManagingCursor(model);

   listView.setAdapter(new ShoppingListAdapter(this, model));

Comment: just pass `0` for `int flags`. don't use `startManagingCursor()`, it's deprecated. `listView.setAdapter(new ShoppingListAdapter(this, model, 0));`

Comment: it's a good habit to post the errors that you're getting. but in this case, i can guess. you should be using: `import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;`. if you're not, substitute it for the one that you might be running. if you're left with no choice, just take out the flags.