# Android: not able to strikethrough textview in a listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am trying to *strikethrough* a `textview` of a `listview`. I created a string of fruits and another string having values as 1 or 0, if value is1, I want to strikeout that fruit. So as per below code, Apple should be striked out.

Below is my code, I can see system executed line-`row.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);`, But still Apple entry is not seen as strikes out.

Please help.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] values = new String[]{"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango"};
        String[] brk = new String[]{"1", "0", "0", "0"};
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shopList);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        System.out.println("value of child count is-" + adapter.getCount());


        for (int t = 0; t < adapter.getCount(); t++) {
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Inside loop");
            String itemValue = (String) adapter.getItem(t);
            TextView row = (TextView) adapter.getView(t, null, null);
            System.out.println("item value -" + itemValue);
            System.out.println("corresponding brk -" + brk[t]);
            if (brk[t].equals("1")) {
                row.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                System.out.println("striked -" + brk[t]);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Layoutfile-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="dhritiapps.dummylv.MainActivity">

<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/shopList"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your adapter

Comment: Is this similar to what you need ? pls check it out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658052/set-paint-strike-thru-text-flag-in-textview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to strike through text in an app widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881553/is-there-an-easy-way-to-strike-through-text-in-an-app-widget)

Answer (score 1):

You can StrikeOut text by `Spanneble` String:

```
tv.setText(s, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) tv.getText();
spannable.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan();, 0, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I porpose that you will make a CustomAdapter where you will use the setPainFlags when the view is created and displayed.
2. if you decide to not create your own adapter then try to use setPainFlags AFTER you attach the adapter to the listView

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
row.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

OR

```
.setPaintFlags( Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

OR 
You can use Spannablestring

http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html